# JavaScript "opener.functionName" doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, popup

I have two files - index.html and popup01.html . What I would like to do is call a function in index.html when the popup is closed. I spent a lot of time searching through SO but I cannot get "opener.onPopupClose" to work.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Window</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <a href="popup01.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'popup01')">Popup 01</a>
</body>
<script>
    function popup(mylink, windowname) {
        if (! window.focus) return true;
        var href;
        if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href = mylink;
        else href = mylink.href;
        window.open(href, windowname, 'scrollbars=yes');
        return false;
    }

    function onPopupClose(popupname) {
        console.log("test");
        //console.log(popupname);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

And here is the popup01,html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Popup 01</title>    
    </head>
    <body onbeforeunload="opener.onPopupClose('popup01');">
            <h1>Popup 01</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The word "test" doesn't display on index.html console. I have tried "javascript:window.opener", "window.opener", and such headbanging, but the function onPopupClose doesn't trigger.

I would accept any solution, including jQuery. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is working as desired for me in chrome, maybe it could be a browser issue?

Comment: Are you accessing the pages using HTTP(S)? If you're trying to open them directly from disk, `file://` often clashes with the same-origin policy, so the pages may be blocked from communicating. – If you don't have an HTTP server setup, this may help: [Big list of http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

Comment: Just tried it online, console is empty, but thank you alot @Jonathan.

Comment: @idkxd - Tried it in FF and Chrome, no luck.

Comment: I used :

        <script>
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                window.opener.onPopupClose('popup01');
            };
        </script>

and it works ! Thank you guys, sincerely.